# Things to consider for a mid-tower PC to be mounted in a van

Tags: hardware

I need to adapt an existing mid-tower case PC to be mounted in a van for data acquisition.

Is there any advice on how to avoid vibrations and shocks to eventually damage the PC?

The van is already built so my only option is to act on the PCs.

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be a tower? Something designed for shocks - a laptop - would seem a better choice, especially with an SSD.

Comment: Unfortunately the PCs are already there (we have two mid-tower).

Comment: Could it be mounted in a frame and then bungie cord the frame to the side of the van? Or take a look at Dell's [Rugged Laptops](http://www.dell.com/xfr).

Comment: The SSD idea is still good either way. I'd also look for cables that latch into place (or consider gluing things down the way OEMs do) to avoid shaking them loose... that of course just opens more problems

Comment: One thing that will minimize the shock and vibration is to turn the van off. ;)

Comment: @RobM we have SSD for os and software and hard disks for data (we need more than 1TB)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A long time ago we used a fairly standard PC chassis on a crane, shock damped with rubber shock dampers.  I don't remember the brand of those dampers (but they looked like [these](http://www.ava-antivibrationmountings.co.uk/Products.aspx)) but I do remember that the calculation of the dampers was done by the seller's technical department, as the type and stiffness to use depend on the type of vibrations to expect (frequency, amplitude).  As the installation has been in service for 5 years without any defects in the PC's I think it's safe to conclude that these dampers worked quite well.

Note: even with dampers I would avoid harddisks, go for SSD's instead.

Answer (score 7):

Mount your equipment in a [shock case](http://www.rackmountsolutions.net/SKB_Shock_Mount_Case_Rack_Entry.asp), *or* use a [ruggedized industrial computer](http://www.nexcom.com/Products/mobile-computing-solutions/in-vehicle-pc).

[Purpose-built vehicle-mount PCs *do* exist...](http://www.nexcom.com/Products/mobile-computing-solutions/in-vehicle-pc)

[image]